# Selecting the numbers in data that satisfy a relationship with respect to a threshold

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

`Rip01` is a list of numbers. It's length is 128.
`PercentualeTaglio` is a number.
I would like to create a list which selects from `Rip01` just the numbers greater than `PercentualeTaglio` and put a zero instead of all the numbers smaller than `PercentualeTaglio`. 
I wrote this code:

```
a = Table[If[Rip01[[k]] > PercentualeTaglio, Rip01[[k]], 0], {k, 1, 128}]
```

But when I evaluate `a = Rip01`. 
If I try to put "<" instead of ">":

```
a = Table[If[Rip01[[k]] < PercentualeTaglio, Rip01[[k]], 0], {k, 1, 128}]
```

I get a list of all zeros.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I meant, when I evaluate I get a=Rip01.

Comment: Use Chop... Chop[Rip01, PercentualeTaglio] to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about Chop. Anyway, I would still like to know why my code did not work... 

@Anjar Kumar. Rip01 is just a list of measures I took.

Comment: probably `PercentualeTaglio` has a value smaller than the smallest value in your list; if every element in your list is greater than the value in `PercentualeTaglio` then `If` returns `0` as instructed

Comment: also, you could try `Thread[head[Rip01,PercentualeTaglio]]/.head[x_,y_]:>If[Greater[x,y],x,0.]` in order to obtain the first table in the question; replace `Greater` with `Less` to obtain the second table in the question; using `Table` to access indices for `Part` is not something you'd generally want to do

Comment: `data // # UnitStep[# - PercentualeTaglio] &` is another possibility

Answer (score 2):

Here are other solutions:

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
Rip01 = RandomInteger[99, 128];
PercentualeTaglio = 50;
```

You can use:

```
Clip[Rip01, {PercentualeTaglio, Max@Rip01}, {0, 0}]
```

or:

```
Rip01 /. t_ /; t < PercentualeTaglio -> 0
```

or:

```
If[# > PercentualeTaglio, #, 0] & /@ Rip01
```

Result is always:

```
{
54, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 0, 0, 0, 81, 87, 0, 88, 98, 0, 
0, 0, 71, 0, 66, 66, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 78, 68, 65, 
82, 64, 0, 63, 98, 0, 60, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0, 78, 
69, 0, 0, 99, 60, 0, 81, 0, 77, 69, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 50, 
0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 91, 0, 72, 0, 86, 0, 58, 64, 66, 64, 
0, 65, 0, 0, 0, 88, 78, 82, 0, 68, 97, 61, 0, 53, 81, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 96, 99, 0, 81, 64, 73, 0, 96, 89, 0, 0, 58, 65, 
58, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 77, 94, 0, 60, 0, 90, 0, 56
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There a lots of ways of performing the task you want to do. Here is a functional approach based on the built-in function [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

You don't supply any sample data, so I contrive some.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomInteger[99, 128]
```

> ```
> {54, 66, 4, 15, 6, 3, 95, 32, 48, 3, 81, 87, 22, 88, 98, 48, 44, 36, 71,  
>  46, 66, 66, 98, 35, 41, 36, 22, 28, 83, 78, 68, 65, 82, 64, 24,63, 98, 
>  47, 60, 8, 60, 32, 17, 26, 53, 26, 20, 78, 69, 25, 36, 99, 60, 21, 81, 
>  31, 77, 69, 8, 36, 3, 83, 1, 50, 14, 78, 25, 32, 22, 25, 91, 1, 72, 40, 
>  86, 4, 58, 64, 66, 64, 20, 65, 15, 26, 35, 88, 78, 82, 20, 68, 97, 61, 
>  30, 53, 81, 1, 29, 18, 9, 96, 99, 26, 81, 64, 73, 37, 96, 89, 43, 18, 
>  58, 65, 58, 22, 44, 28, 78, 35, 49, 4, 77, 94, 7, 60, 9, 90, 14, 56}
> ```

Now I define a function that given a threshold and a relationship to apply, returns a function that can select the numbers in data that satisfy the relationship with respect to the threshold.

```
choose[threshold_, func_] := Select[func[#, threshold] &]
```

Setting the threshold at 50, this function can split the data into those numbers > 50 and ≤ 50 like so

```
choose[50, Greater] @ data
```

> ```
> {54, 66, 95, 81, 87, 88, 98, 71, 66, 66, 98, 83, 78, 68, 65, 
>  82, 64, 63, 98, 60, 60, 53, 78, 69, 99, 60, 81, 77, 69, 83, 78, 
>  91, 72, 86, 58, 64, 66, 64, 65, 88, 78, 82, 68, 97, 61, 53, 81, 
>  96, 99, 81, 64, 73, 96, 89, 58, 65, 58, 78, 77, 94, 60, 90, 56}
> ```

```
choose[50, LessEqual] @ data
```

> ```
>  {4, 15, 6, 3, 32, 48, 3, 22, 48, 44, 36, 46, 35, 41, 36, 22, 28, 24, 47, 8, 32, 
>   17, 26, 26, 20, 25, 36, 21, 31, 8, 36, 3, 1, 50, 14, 25, 32, 22, 25, 1, 40, 4, 20, 15, 
>   26, 35, 20, 30, 1, 29, 18, 9, 26, 37, 43, 18, 22, 44, 28, 35, 49, 4, 7, 9, 14}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using m_goldberg's and mrz's example setup:

```
Rip01 UnitStep[Rip01 - PercentualeTaglio]
```

> {54, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95, 0, 0, 0, 81, 87, 0, 88, 98, 0, 0, 0, 71, 0, 66, 66, 98,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 78, 68, 65, 82, 64, 0, 63, 98, 0, 60, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 53, 0, 0,
>   78, 69, 0, 0, 99, 60, 0, 81, 0, 77, 69, 0, 0, 0, 83, 0, 50, 0, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 91,
>   0, 72, 0, 86, 0, 58, 64, 66, 64, 0, 65, 0, 0, 0, 88, 78, 82, 0, 68, 97, 61, 0, 53,
>   81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 99, 0, 81, 64, 73, 0, 96, 89, 0, 0, 58, 65, 58, 0, 0, 0, 78, 0,
>   0, 0, 77, 94, 0, 60, 0, 90, 0, 56}